# How do IDE apps on Android build APK?

Tags: applications, apk

Apps like [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui), [SketchWare](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.besome.sketch), and AppBuilder can build APK files directly on Android devices.

How do those apps do it?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I'll post somewhere else. The documentation doesn't cover this topic btw

Comment: Sorry, I misread the title as "Android Studio" and reopened the question to give a chance to clarify. Note that since this community focuses on end-users instead of developers, we could probably provide an overview of what those apps do to generate an APK. However, if you want the detail on how to do it on your own app, take note that development-related questions are off-topic.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. This would be just enough

Comment: The tools for compiling and building an Android APK are open source. Therefore you can compile them for e.g. arm and build an Android development environment on-device. It looks like AIDE works this way. I have seen tools like `aapt` and `aidl` in the AIDE apk file and it contains a lot of sample Android apps in source code form (Gradle project). Using e.g Termux app it should also be possible to compile Android projects  via gradle on command-line.

Comment: Fantastic explanation, Robert. Now I got it. Can you, please and kindly, provide some tutorial or documentation about this?

Comment: @Robert nevermind, found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9731518/13217410

Comment: The linked interview is totally outdated as it talks about the no more used Android development plugins for Eclipse.

Comment: Yes, but the rest of the toolchain is almost the same, if I understood well

Comment: There are still programs that do more or less the same job, but nearly every tool in the Android build chain has been replaced in the last years. This schema diagram is a bit newer: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/build-workflow

Comment: I see. Thanks for telling